# SQL date check within set number of days

Tags: sql, oracle

Im trying to find out how many clients viewed a property within 14 days of May 20, 2004, either before or after. Not really sure at all how to go about this.

Im assuming i need to group it and use a having?

EDIT: I am using oracle now

```
select count(*)
from VIEWING
WHERE CLAUSE?
```

Comment: I don't think you need either.  What type of database is it?  sql server?  oracle?

Comment: You have forgotten to tell us relevant table structure (name of table, name and datatype of pertinent columns) and RDBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit #1, since you are using Oracle, you can use:

```
select count(*) TotalClients
from yourtable
where dt >= (to_date('2004-05-20', 'yyyy-mm-dd') - INTERVAL '14' DAY)
  and dt <= (to_date('2004-05-20', 'yyyy-mm-dd') + INTERVAL '14' DAY)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/48f46/13)

<strike>Based on some of your previous questions you were using MySQL.</strike>

If you are using MySQL then you can use the [`DATE_ADD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function to get the date range and then use `count(*)` to return all records from those dates:

```
select count(*) TotalClients
from yourtable
where dt >= date_add(str_to_date('2004-05-20', '%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL -14 day)
  and dt <= date_add(str_to_date('2004-05-20', '%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL 14 day)
```

Comment: ORA-00904: "DT": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 60 Column: 7. Keep Getting this error when trying to run it Copyed your where clause

Comment: select count(*)
    from VIEWING
    where dt >= (to_date('2004-05-20', 'yyyy-mm-dd') - INTERVAL '14' DAY)
  and dt <= (to_date('2004-05-20', 'yyyy-mm-dd') + INTERVAL '14' DAY);

Comment: @JohnAyers you need to replace the `dt` with the date column in your view

Answer (score 2):

For a one time query with that specific date,

```
select count(*) clients
from yourtable
where yourdatefield >= {d'2004-05-06'}
and yourdatefield < {d'2004-06-08'}
```

You might want to consult a calendar to see if those dates are correct.